# Best supervised learning algorithm for small data

Tags: image, image-processing, machine-learning, computer-vision, artificial-intelligence

I am wonder which supervised learning algorithm is best for generalising small data. I have a feature vector of size (64 x 122) where 64 is one dimension feature vector for the image path which 122 is number of images. Each patch is 16 x 16 pixels.

I used multi class support vector machine but the result is low success rate, which increase with greater image number. I don't want to increase my image patch number but hopping to achieve good classification rate.

Can i get some idea on this? How to train small data using Supervised learning method.

Comment: Surely you've heard of [the no free lunch theorem](http://www.no-free-lunch.org/)?

Comment: with a very small train set I would first try the simplest thing possible which is probably knn

Comment: The single biggest improvement always comes from more training data. Is it possible to synthesise training data in your case?

Comment: sorry but what synthesise training  means

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some possible attempts:

1. Some simple clustering methods such as k-means;
2. Logistic regression;
3. Increase the feature number then use linear SVM (do not use other kernels).